# Invalid argument. IE 7-8

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm using the MooTools library and I'm seeing the error of "Invalid Argument" on the `.setStyle()` method for IE 7 and 8.  The line of code that's throwing the error is the following:

```
this.style[property] = value;
```

I understand this is something I need to take up with the MooTools community, but I was curious as to why IE would throw this error. The `this` is referring to an `HTMLDivElement`, BTW.

Comment: Where does `property` come from?

Comment: What are the values of `property` and `value`?

Comment: The property is width and the value is NaNpx, which is probably where the error is coming from.

Comment: Check this link http://www.mooforum.net/solutions12/mootools-not-working-t2911.html

Comment: @SpencerCarnage: Any chance the initial value being passed in us `'auto'`?

Comment: No, everything coming is either zero or an actual number. Some of them were numbers with decimals so I'm using Math.round() so see if that will potentially fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ran across this problem LOADS of times, all you need to do is typecast your value for width as an integer before you assign it, you are using mootools so do this

```
this.style[property] = value.toInt();
```

Thats using what you have your better off actually using mootools (especially for opacity and stuff since it will actually handle IE as well, and using this:

```
this.setStyle('property', value.toInt());
```

I am sure you are preforming some calculations, then supplying IE with a `double` value for pixel, and older versions of IE will not take a decimal number as a pixel.